# Vimperator - is there any way to edit text?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions, vimperator

I'd like to know if there is any way to edit text in Vimperator (for example input boxes or Gmails web interface)? The way one edits text in Vim and can navigate e.g. the use of "p", "yy" and "dd" etc.

If there is any way how to do this in Firefox, please share it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/75652/is-there-a-firefox-add-on-to-use-vim-to-edit-textboxes

Answer (score 6):

ctrl+i open a external editor

```
set editor='gvim -f'
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Simply navigate to an input field or box by clicking on it or tabbing to it. This will automatically put Vimperator into `INSERT` mode and you are free to type.

Comment: Yes, this is natural, but I wanted something more like 'visual mode' to be able to do dd, dw, d3w and such.
I started using pentadactyl since, this is possible by C-t from within insert mode.

Comment: @AoeAoe Nice trick, this also works with Vimperator.

Answer (score 0):

If you press Control+i within an input box vimperator will create a vim's background process (by default with gvim, but you can change it in the editor variable), and you can edit that way, when you do `:wq` on that vim's process it copies the buffer into the input box

Other than that, you can use [wasavi](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/wasavi/), which turn every input text in a vim's clone.

Comment: <C>+i is already binded to the insertion of `*emphasized text*` on SE when you're editing an answer, so it isn't picked up by vimperator.

Comment: i don't use this to ask as much to learn to use it. 
Why? I've made my way to fix my own things faster.

Comment: In which instance *would* you ask a question?

Comment: I try to do it. But since I follow SO's best practices for explaining the problem , 100% of the times I had a problem (from my last question's date :P ` Feb 29 '16 at 13:12 127.0.0.1 873 ` ) in which I would ask here I solved it while I was explaining it.

Comment: Could you elaborate in a more simple manner? I seem to be missing your message.

Comment: split and conquer

Comment: I presume you mean dividing a problem up into managable pieces, by *split and conquer*. My solution was to use a keymapping, for what it's worth.

Comment: whatever just chilling i do not care about anything any longer :).